# How to insert a character at the beginning of a string attribute in spirit qi

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I have the following rule:

```
rule<std::string::const_iterator, std::string()> t_ffind, t_sim, t_hash, t_state;

t_ffind = hold[(attr('$') >> t_sim >> t_hash >> t_state)] | t_sim;
```

which means that I could find `t_sim` alone or followed by `t_hash` and `t_state`, if it is alone `t_ffind` will take the exact value of `t_sim`, in the other case I will also insert a marking character at the beginning of the string.

but if I write the rule like that I would be parsing `t_sim` twice, so I modified the rule to:

```
t_ffind = t_sim >> -(qi::hold[t_hash >> t_state]);
```

but remains the problem of inserting the character if `(t_hash >> t_state)` is present, I think the solution could be some semantic action at the end:

```
t_ffind = t_sim >> -(qi::hold[t_hash >> t_state])[];
```

but I can't find how to do that, also if there's other solution that doesn't involve semantic action would be even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the idea of "adding a magic character to some unrelated attribute" constitutes a questionable design choice. In general, I recommend to keep parsing and program logic separate. So I'd parse into

```
namespace ast {
  struct t_ffind {
      std::string t_sim;
      boost::optional<std::string> t_hash, t_state; // or whatever the types are
  };
}
```

Or, if you really don't have a reason to model the hash/state tokens into separate fields, you could do

```
namespace ast {
  struct t_ffind {
      std::string t_sim_hash_state;
      bool sim_only;
  };
}
```

but it would get more complicated to set `sim_only` from within a semantic action. This is getting close to the issue you are facing.

### Your Wish

Just for fun, let's see what we could do. Firstly, optimizing the repeated parsing of `t_sim` smells like a premature optimization. But perhaps you could use a semantic action to alter `_val`:

```
t_ffind %= t_sim >> -(as_string[t_hash >> t_state] [ insert(_val, begin(_val), '$') ]);
```

Note the use of `as_string[]` to glue the attributes of t_hash and t_state together, so the automatic attribute propagation keeps working. I strongly suspect this to be an - obviously - bigger performance hit than potentially parsing `t_sim` twice.

You can try to wrangle more control from Spirit:

```
t_ffind = (t_sim >> -(as_string[t_hash >> t_state])) 
    [ if_(_2) [ _val = '$' + _1 + *_2 ].else_ [ _val = _1 ] ];
```

Still using the `as_string` intermediate concatenation. You can forgo it:

```
t_ffind = (t_sim >> -(t_hash >> t_state))
    [ if_(_2) 
        [ _val = '$' + _1 + at_c<0>(*_2) + at_c<1>(*_2) ]
      .else_ 
        [ _val = _1 ] 
    ];
```

By now, we're getting ridiculously far adrift for very little gain (if any). I'd suggest either

1. writing it the naive way:

   ```
   t_ffind = hold[(attr('$') >> t_sim >> t_hash >> t_state)] | t_sim;
   ```
2. fixing your AST to mirror the thing you're parsing
3. writing the parser manually

### Full Demo

All the above variations:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dee8937e0b08cd68)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_fusion.hpp>

int main() {
    using namespace boost::spirit::qi;

    rule<std::string::const_iterator, std::string()> 
        t_sim   = "sim",
        t_hash  = +digit,
        t_state = raw[lit("on")|"off"],
        t_ffind;

    for (auto initialize_t_ffind : std::vector<std::function<void()> > {
     [&] { t_ffind = hold[(attr('$') >> t_sim >> t_hash >> t_state)] | t_sim; },
     [&] {
             // this works:
             using boost::phoenix::insert;
             using boost::phoenix::begin;
             t_ffind %= t_sim >> -(as_string[t_hash >> t_state] [ insert(_val, begin(_val), '$') ]);
         },
     [&] { 
            // this works too:
            using boost::phoenix::if_;
            t_ffind = (t_sim >> -(as_string[t_hash >> t_state])) 
                [ if_(_2) 
                    [ _val = '$' + _1 + *_2 ]
                  .else_ 
                    [ _val = _1 ] 
                ];
         },
     [&] {
             // "total control":
            using boost::phoenix::if_;
            using boost::phoenix::at_c;
            t_ffind = (t_sim >> -(t_hash >> t_state))
                [ if_(_2) 
                    [ _val = '$' + _1 + at_c<0>(*_2) + at_c<1>(*_2) ]
                  .else_ 
                    [ _val = _1 ] 
                ];
        } })

     {
         initialize_t_ffind();

         for (std::string const s : { "sim78off", "sim" })
         {
             auto f = s.begin(), l = s.end();
             std::string result;
             if (parse(f, l, t_ffind, result)) {
                 std::cout << "Parsed: '" << result << "'\n";
             } else {
                 std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
             }

             if (f != l) {
                 std::cout << "Remaining input: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Prints:

```
Parsed: '$sim78off'
Parsed: 'sim'
Parsed: '$sim78off'
Parsed: 'sim'
Parsed: '$sim78off'
Parsed: 'sim'
Parsed: '$sim78off'
Parsed: 'sim'
```

Comment: very complete answer, I will think further about the issues you pointed